# Is "mortal" the woman's son?

Tags: meaning-in-context

source [THE BLACK VEIL](http://www.ibiblio.org/ebooks/Dickens/Dickens_Veil.pdf#search=%27The+Black+Veil+by+Charles+Dickens+full%27)

> In the transient gleam of recollection and consciousness which
>   preceded her death, a prayer for his welfare and protection, as
>   fervent as **mortal** ever breathed, rose from the lips of this poor
>   friendless creature.

The poor creature is the woman with the black veil and "his" welfare is the doctor's welfare. Is "mortal" the woman's son?

Answer (score 4):

No, here "mortal" is a generic, meaning "any mortal man or woman".  It's just an expression to indicate the prayer was particularly intense and sincere.